# Getting ( vanna, volga ) factors beyond Greeks from FinancialDerivative[ ] function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, quantitative-finance

Mathematica's built-in **`FinancialDerivative[]`** function calculates financial option price and a few sensitivities ( a.k.a. Greeks ), namely `delta`, `gamma`, `vega`, `rho` and `theta`.

I am trying to implement a so-called Vanna-Volga Method for pricing FX exotic options, which requires calculating also `vanna`, i.e. **`D[price, volatility, spot]`**, and `volga`, i.e. **`D[Price, {volatility, 2}]`**.

But the `FinancialDerivative[]` function, as-is, neither computes `vanna`/`volga`, nor allows me to use the analytical `D[ , ]`.

Is there a solution I haven't tried?

Many, many thanks.
Poomjai Nacaskul